# Twilio import error: Module cannot be null

Tags: react-native, twilio, webstorm, expo

I've done `npm install --save react-native-twilio` and `react-native-link` in my EXPO react-native project. the code compiles without error. But when I add this line of code:

```
const Twilio = require('react-native-twilio');
```

in my file, it reports an error says Module can not be null.

I think it is because I didnt link my twilio library to the project right, but I dont know how to fix it, can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `react-native-twilio` has native dependencies and with EXPO, its not possible to include custom native modules. The only way is for you to `eject` your app to create native builds.

[Official docs for ejecting] (https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app)